# Using Grid with Bootstrap. I want to extend a sidebar all the way to the footer, but it stops about halfway down

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and have created a grid. One of my grid areas is a sidebar/menu that is a column of photos. I'd like this column to extend all the way to my footer. It worked originally, and then I added a few more sections and it now stops about halfway up the page.

I've tried adding more photos to the sidebar, but that doesn't help. I've also tried reducing the size of the newly added sections so they don't have a width of 100% because I thought that might be preventing the sidebar from continuing down.

Some visual aspects get messed up when I add the code to Codepen, but it should still be easy to figure out. I've added a light blue right border to the menu so I can see where it stops. Here's a link to the Codepen: https://codepen.io/amandathedev/pen/zyEyze

Here's the relevant portion, I believe:

```
grid-template-areas:
"menu header"
"menu main"
"menu flex"
"menu footer";

#menu {
grid-area: menu;
border-right: 1px solid lightblue;
}

.menu-photo {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

I don't want to paste the whole section here, as it is basically a list of links to photos. Thank you!

Comment: dont make different div for carousel and contact form , add into in your regular parent div

Comment: Ahh, that fixed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: use `display: contents;` for your contact form